# how to auto login users in my website when they visit from trusted web sites

Tags: security, web, oauth

I have a web app ( App1)  which uses Oauth2.0 compliant server for authenticating the users, There is another web app ( App2) which uses different login system but is a trusted source,

so, A user login to App2 and then click a link which takes them to App1 and will be asked to login and if the attempt is successful, all their subsequent visits to App1 from App2 at any later date should auto login the user.

This is just to facilitate to  users of App2 to gain access to App1 seamlessly.

can someone please suggest me some ideas?

Comment: Don't you also need to implement OAuth on App2? That was either app can authorise the user.

Comment: No App2 is going to stay with the same login system, I am just trying to find  a seamless way to integrate/authorize users ( without sharing the credentials or storing it twice ) in App1 when they visit from App2.

Comment: It just seems silly to have gone to the effort of implementing OAuth and then you fudge in a non-standard authorisation system in order to facilitate another very similar requirement which is what OAuth was designed to do in the first place.